# Query regarding Google Protocol Buffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

```
message Person {
    required string name = 1;
    required int32 id = 2;
    optional string email = 3; 
}
```

The above is a snippet from addrbook.proto file mentioned in Google Protocol Buffer tutorials.
The requirement is that, the application that is being developed will need to decode binary data received from a socket.For example,name, id and e-mail represented as binary data.
Now, id can be read as an integer. But I am really not sure how to read name and email considering that these two can be of variable lengths. (And unfortunately, I do not get lengths prefixed before these two fields)
Application is expected to read these kind of data from a variety of sources. Our objective is to make a decoder/adapter for the different types of data originating from these sources. Then there could be different types of messages from same source too.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> But I am really not sure how to read name and email considering that these two can be of variable lengths.

The entire point of a serializer such as protobuf is that *you don't need to worry about that*. Specifically, in the case of protobuf strings are always prefixed by their length in bytes (using UTF-8 encoding, and varint encoding of the length).

> And unfortunately, I do not get lengths prefixed before these two fields

Then you aren't processing protobuf data. Protobuf is a specific data format, in the same way that xml or json is a data format. Any conversation involving "protocol buffers" only makes sense if you are actually discussing the protobuf format, or data serialized *using* that format.

Protocol buffers is not an arbitrary data handling API. It will not allow you to process data in any format other than protobuf.

Comment: Thanks for that Marc. My idea was to decode the data coming from devices sending messages in different formats , apply some business logic on the parsed data , write a reply back to the device or write to file or store in a message queue or store in a database etc. Now, the data written to file or DB could be used by a different application. I was planning to give the GPB protocol definition file to the other party to decipher the message sent from our system. Looks like i am going wrong in the basics itself

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to re-implement Protocol Buffers by hand; you don't need to do that (though I'm sure it would be fun).  Google provides C, Java, and Python implementations to serialize and de-serialize content in protobuf format as part of the [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) project.